# Is the T-Mobile iPhone 6s from Apple.com Unlocked?

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-carriers

If I buy the T-Mobile iPhone 6s from Apple for the full price (no contract), will it be carrier unlocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - T-Mobile phones of all versions are factory unlocked. iPhone 6s/plus will be just like the iPhone 6/plus in that regard.

This year, you can buy phones unlocked on Apple's payment plan as well if you prefer that over paying full price.

Comment: By "all versions" are factory unlocked, do you mean that all versions of iPhones are unlocked, or all phones in general from T-Mobile are unlocked?

Comment: You asked about full price? They are unlocked...

Answer (score -1):

I contacted many apple repersentative and they keep saying no, but if you contact Apple in Spanish, those representative will say yes.